# Драйвера устройств в Linux

Tags: linux, c, драйвер

Не могу никак разобраться со структурами `dev_t` и `cdev`. Вообще я новичок в этом деле, поэтому заранее прошу объяснить очень доступным языком.
Допустим, мы зарегистрировали (зарезервировали) старший и младший номера устройств, ассоциируемый с нашим драйвером:

```
res_of_reg = alloc_chrdev_region(&dev, minor_first, minor_count, name);
major = MAJOR(dev);
```

Далее, мы хотим сказать ядру, что по этому номеру будет использоваться символьное устройство

```
cdev_init(&mydev,&dev_fops);
mydev.owner = THIS_MODULE;
res_of_reg = cdev_add(&mydev, dev, minor_count);
```

Вопрос в следующем: правильно ли я понимаю, что настоящее устройство после компиляции модуля нужно связать с этим номером, чтобы он ассоциировался с драйвером символьного устройства? Ведь заранее устройство не может знать свои номера, я выделяю для работы с ним мажор и минор, а потом должен связать? Или это работает чуть иначе!
И наоборот, если устройство знает свой номер, то почему я делаю всё динамически в модуле драйвера? 
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Номера -- абстракция. Непонятно, что вы имеете в виду под "связыванием". Устройству не нужно сейчас знать эти номера наперёд.